# TableVIewでセルがない時に「情報なし」と表示されるようにしたいです

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

(CoreDataを使っています)
TableViewに一件もセルがない時に、「情報なし」と表示されるようにしたいのですが、
方法が全くわかりません。
iphoneの標準の時計アプリのアラームで、アラーム情報がない時に
「アラームなし」と表示されているので同じことは出来ると思うのですが...

もしもやり方をお知りの方がいらっしゃいましたら
教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: @dokubeko
回答ありがとうございます。
やってみます^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewを、同じframeのUILabelで覆うだけです。
同じ親ビューに追加して、必要に応じてテーブルを-bringSubviewToFront:するなりhiddenを変えるなりインスタンスごと消すなりします。

Answer (score 1):

自分で回答です。
最善の解決法ではないと思いますがやっとできたため、
同じようなことで悩んでいる人が、もしもいた時のために
投稿しておきます

まず行いたいtableviewControllerのヘッダで

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *label;
```

のようにラベルの使用を宣言します。

次に実装ファイルで最初に読み込んだ時に、情報が一件もなければNoInformationとでるようにします。

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

// 対象エンティティを指定します。
    NSEntityDescription *entity
    = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourEntityName"  　　　　inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// キャッシュサイズや上限を指定します。
//ここはコピペなのでいらないかもしれません
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:0];



    NSError *error = nil;
    NSInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext  countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
//ここでコンテキストの件数をNSIntegerに入れて件数がゼロの場合はラベルを表示します
    if(count==0){
    _label =[[UILabel alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:_label];
    _label.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                             self.tableView.frame.origin.y-60,//位置がずれてる分修正してます
                             self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                             self.tableView.frame.size.height);

    _label.textColor =[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _label.text =@"NoInformation";
    [_label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];//文字中央寄せ
    _label.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_label];
}
```

次にセルの削除が行われた時にに表示するようにします

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:    (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 　*)indexPath {
　　　　if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    　　NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    　　[context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];


    　　NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    // 対象エンティティを指定します。
   　　 NSEntityDescription *entity
    = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourEntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];//セル削除後のデータ件数が必要なので上で使ったcontextを使います
    　　[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // キャッシュサイズや上限を指定します。
    　　[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    　　[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:0];



    　　NSError *error = nil;
    　　NSInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    　　if(count==0){
    　　_label =[[UILabel alloc]init];
    　　[self.view addSubview:_label];
        _label.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                                 self.tableView.frame.origin.y-60,
                                 self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                 self.tableView.frame.size.height);

    　　_label.textColor =[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    　　_label.text =@"NoInformation";
    　　[_label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    　　_label.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    　　[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_label];
    }

    if (![context save:&error]) {//先ほどは件数取得のためだけなので不要でしたが、ここはデータセーブが必要です
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
  }
}
```

そしてセルの追加時にラベルを取り除くようにします

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
  [_label removeFromSuperview];
//(以下略)
}
```

現在これで正しく動いているのを確認できています。